# Google Tag Manager vs react-ga4

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, react-ga

I am setting up analytics for a new website. I have seen many articles/references detailing how to set up analytics using Google Tag Manager. I have also seen articles that use react-ga or react-ga4 npm package.

It looks to me like the end result is the same, so I am wondering if anyone has advice on which I should be using for me react app.